# Inserting a file into table in sql server using Stored Procedure Giving error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bulk-load

```
declare  @path nvarchar(max)

set @path='C:\a\SQLQuery1.sql'

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '@path',SINGLE_BLOB) as res
```

I am trying to execute this particular block in SQL server but its throwing error saying that

> Can not bulk load ,@path does not exist.

But If I Provide the path explicitly in the last line instead of @path then its successfully running.
Any help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @path nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @path = N'C:\a\SQLQuery1.sql';
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@path+''',SINGLE_BLOB) as res';

EXEC(@sql);
```